# Bash looping over files in different directories and print output

Tags: bash, shell

I have `*.vcf`, `*.vcf.vcfidx` and `*.vcf.idx` files in directory `/mypath/mydir/`. I want to loop over `.vcf` files only using command below (for file 1):

command for one vcf file:

```
vcf-subset -c sample.txt vcffile1.vcf | bgzip  -c > output_vcfile1.vcf_.vcf.gz
```

Can someone please help loop over all the .vcf (not `vcf.vcfidx` or `vcf.idx`) files and get the output for each file in designated directory `/get/inthis/dir/` using the command shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use glob pattern `*.vcf`:

```
for i in *.vcf; do echo "$i"; done
```

The glob pattern `*.vcf` will match only files ending in `.vcf`.

Your command:

```
for i in *.vcf; do
    vcf-subset -c sample.txt "$i" | bgzip  -c > /get/inthis/dir/output_"$i"_.vcf.gz
done
```

---

If you have to search for `.vcf` files in a specific directory e.g. `/foo/bar/`, do:

```
for i in /foo/bar/*.vcf; do
    vcf-subset -c sample.txt "$i" | bgzip  -c > /get/inthis/dir/output_"${i##*/}"_.vcf.gz
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do you mention which directory to look for vcf files and which directory to use to print output  file?

Comment: Thanks. So `$i` indicates each `.vcf` file here? It will not loop over any `.vcf.vcfidx` files? Just want to get this clarified..

Comment: Thanks. How do you mention the  path for the directory for `.vcf` files before `$i`

Comment: If you do `for i in /foo/bar/*.vcf; do`, it prints the full path for `$i` in `/get/inthis/dir/output_"$i"_.vcf.gz`, generating error: `no such file or directory`. What would be the best way to search for the files and have only file names in `$i` instead of full path

Comment: Thanks a lot! So `i##` removes the path?

Comment: @MAPK Yes, this is called parameter expansion..check parameter expansion section of `man bash`